# Sort an array of arrays by date in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of arrays which the first field is a date (in string format). I want to sort them by the date (asceding), so I can use it for further calculations.

I identify two tasks on my problem. First, parse strings as dates and then sort.

```
a = new Date(Date.parse('1/11/2014 13:42:54'));
console.log(a)
```

Return `11th of January` whereas I need `1st of November`

Then, I the sorting should work like this:

```
function compare(a,b) {
  if (a[0] < b[0])
     return -1;
  if (a[0] > b[0])
    return 1;
  return 0;
}

myarray.sort(compare);
```

So, how  can I solve the problem with the dates to make it works on sorting function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just capture the date and month part, swap them and do `Date.parse` and `new Date`, like this

```
function getFormattedDate(dateString) {
    var result = dateString.replace(/(\d+)\/(\d+)(.*)/, function (m, g1, g2, g3) {
        return g2 + "/" + g1 + g3;
    });

    return new Date(Date.parse(result));
}

console.log(getFormattedDate('1/11/2014 13:42:54'));
// Sat Nov 01 2014 13:42:54 GMT+0000 (GMT)
```

Here, the regular expression, `(\d+)\/(\d+)(.*)` will capture three parts of the string, first `(\d+)` captures the date part followed by `/` (escaped as `\/`) and the month part with another `(\d+)` and the rest of the string is captured with `(.*)`. Then we return a new string by swapping the positions of `g2` and `g1` (month and date part).

**Note:** If all you are trying to do is sorting, then you don't need to create a new `Date` object. You can simply use the result of `Date.parse` which is epoch time, like this

```
function getEpochTime(dateString) {
    var result = dateString.replace(/(\d+)\/(\d+)(.*)/, function (m, g1, g2, g3) {
        return g2 + "/" + g1 + g3;
    });

    return Date.parse(result);
}

function comparator(firstDate, secondDate) {
    return getEpochTime(firstDate) - getEpochTime(secondDate);
}
```

and then sort like this

```
var arr = ['3/11/2014 13:42:54',
    '2/11/2014 13:42:54',
    '1/12/2014 13:42:54',
    '1/11/2014 13:43:54'
];

arr.sort(comparator);

console.log(arr);
```

would give you

```
[ '1/11/2014 13:43:54',
  '2/11/2014 13:42:54',
  '3/11/2014 13:42:54',
  '1/12/2014 13:42:54' ]
```

Answer (score 3):

If your dates are in ISO format you can use such a code:

```
myarray.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (new Date(a[0])).getTime() - (new Date(b[0])).getTime();
});
```

Comment: Will this solve the problem of the Dates (get day instead of month and vice versa?)

Comment: getTime() returns absolute miliseconds since epoch, and thus is good for sorting chronologically.

Comment: @Anastasios Ventouris Nope. You have to ensure your dates are in either format of specified [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

Answer (score 1):

With moment.js you can create a moment object using the [String+Format constructor](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

```
moment('1/11/2014 13:42:54', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss')
```

so, if you have an array of arrays which the first field is a date (in string format):

```
array_of_arrays = [
  ['1/11/2014 13:42:54', 'val'],
  ['2/11/2014 13:42:54', true]
];

for(array in array_of_arrays){
     epoch = moment(array.shift,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss').unix();
     array.unshift(epoch);
 }
```

now, you can just do `new Date(epoch)` as instead of complex date objects, we have Unix Epoch which can be easily sorted with inbuid Array.sort something like this

```
function Comparator(a,b){
 if (a[0] < b[0]) return -1;
 if (a[0] > b[0]) return 1;
 return 0;
}
array_of_arrays.sort(Comparator);
```

so now you have `array_of_arrays` sorted as per date

Lastly, if you need more precise answer than this, please share some more sample code.

Answer (score 0):

This is problem:

```
a = new Date(Date.parse('1/11/2014 13:42:54'));
console.log(a)
```

> Return 11th of January whereas I need 1st of November`

Your date format is `dd/mm/yyy`; `Date.parse('1/11/2014 13:42:54')` accepts `mm/dd/yyyy`

Try a date parsing as following:

```
function parseDate(str) {
    var ds = str.match(/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)\s+(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)/);
    // Convert to format: mm/dd/yyyy
    return new Date(ds[3], ds[2] - 1, // month is 0-based
                ds[1], ds[4], ds[5], ds[6]);
}

var arr = [parseDate('3/11/2014 13:42:54'),
  parseDate('2/11/2014 13:42:54'),
  parseDate('1/12/2014 13:42:54'),
  parseDate('1/11/2014 13:43:54')
];

arr.sort();
```

Or:

```
function parseDate(str) {
    var ds = str.match(/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)\s+(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)/);
    // Convert to format: mm/dd/yyyy
    return new Date(ds[3], ds[2] - 1, // month is 0-based
                ds[1], ds[4], ds[5], ds[6]);
}

var arr = ['3/11/2014 13:42:54',
  '2/11/2014 13:42:54',
  '1/12/2014 13:42:54',
  '1/11/2014 13:43:54'
];


arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseDate(a) - parseDate(b);
})
```